# SQL calculating percentage of a group

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I have got a question about calculating the percentage of groups in SQL.

I have a table with different food data. This is the solution I got for my first query:

```
ProductCategory     Total products in Category
Tee, Coffee         225
Cosmetics           492
Sweets              1805
```

**Query:**

```
select productCategory, count(*) as numberOfProducts
from products
group by productCategory
order by productCategory
```

I did a second query filtering out the non-bio products and this is what I got:

```
ProductCategory     Bioproducts in Category
Tee, Coffee         120
Cosmetics           1
Sweets              161
```

**Query:**

```
select productCategory, count(*) as numberofProducts
from products
where bio = 'true'
group by productCategory
order by productCateogry
```

I want to calculate the amount of bio-products in percent for each category. So for the first category the calculation would be (120/225) * 100 = 53,33 %

I tried doing this query:

```
select productCategory, round(count(*)
/ (
select count(*) as numberofProducts
from products) * 100, 2) || ' %' as percentageBio
from products
where bio = 'true'
group by productCategory
order by productCategory
```

but I am getting wrong values.

Is my SQL statement wrong? Does anyone know how I can calculate the percentage rate of bio products for each category?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select productCategory, count(*) as numberofProducts,
       avg(case when bio = 'true' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from products
group by productCategory
order by productCategory;
```

I think this is the simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: That looks simple from a query-writing perspective, but seems like it would end up with a ridiculously inefficient answer performance-wise.  Isn't the subquery method mentioned below going to return a more efficient answer?

Comment: @DylanB . . . Somehow you think that two aggregations and a join are going to be *more* efficient than a single aggregation?  I'm not quite sure how to help you on that one.  This should be the most efficient way to express the logic.

Comment: You're creating an arbitrary numeric value and then averaging it.  I'd think aggregating the values then doing a mathematical total on the whole would be more efficient than this, but maybe you're right....  If there's an index on a table set up in the right way do some versions of SQL store common meta-values like averages and sums? If they did, to use the existing structure instead of creating a magical variable on the fly would be a far cleaner and more efficient solution.

Comment: @DylanBrams . . . You don't have a very good sense of what is expensive and cheap performance wise in a query.  In general, anything that processes data is going to be more expensive than anything that does arithmetic on a single row.  (There are exceptions, but this doesn't come close to being one of them.)

Comment: You're generating an integer in-memory and doing arithmetic on it instead of using two counts of indexed information. From a fundamental algorithmic standpoint, you need to gather the information for the count regardless, but you don't need to reserve the memory for the extra integer and do all the math on it. Where you're essentially building a running average the count just counts something that may already be indexed.
It's odd you think this is arithmetic on a single row; you're generating extra data for each row, then doing arithmetic on that. And I almost flagged that comment as rude.

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculate total count / category in a subquery

```
SELECT productCategory, round(100 * count(*) / tot_count,2)
FROM (SELECT count(*) as tot_count, productCategory cat 
      FROM products 
      GROUP BY productCategory) AS sub,
     products
WHERE bio = 1 and cat = productCategory
GROUP BY productCategory 
ORDER BY productCategory
```